# Test Laravel Controller's try catch

Tags: laravel, testing, mocking, automated-tests, mockery

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and have this controller

```php
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $fileData   = $request->getContent();
    $fileName   = uniqid().'.xlsx';

    try {
        // save file locally
        Storage::disk('local')->put($fileName, $fileData);

        // dispatch to queue
        AnyJob::dispatch($fileName);

        // insert in import_statuses table for status checking
        AnyModel::create([
            'job_id'  => $fileName
        ]);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        error_log($e);

        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Could not save file or queue not found.'
        ], 500);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'OK',
        'jobId'  => $fileName,
    ]);
}
```

And I'm trying to create a test that enters the catch, but I can't get it to work.

I already tried mocking `Storage` and expect methods `disk` and `put` to be called, but it always complains about other methods being called and not expected.

I also tried mocking `AnyJob` and `AnyModel` in many ways but that doesn't seem to affect the request made by `$this->post`.

This is my test method right now:

```php
public function testUploadException()
{
    $xlsxFile = UploadedFile::fake()->create('test.xlsx', 100);

    // ignore Storage and Job real work
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::fake();
    $this->withoutJobs();

    $mock = Mockery::mock('\App\AnyModel');
    $mock
        ->shouldReceive('create')->times(3)
        ->andThrow(new \Exception('any error'));

    $this->app->instance('\App\AnyModel', $mock);

    $response = $this
        ->withHeaders(['content-type' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'])
        ->post('/api/upload', [$xlsxFile]);

    $response
        ->assertStatus(500)
        ->assertJson([
            'error' => 'Could not save file or queue not found.'
        ]);
}
```

And what it returns

```sh
root@3e5d84a4db42:/application/api# vendor/bin/phpunit 
PHPUnit 7.5.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

....F                                                               5 / 5 (100%)

Time: 2.62 seconds, Memory: 20.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\UploadTest::testUploadException
Expected status code 500 but received 200.
Failed asserting that false is true.

/application/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php:133
/application/api/tests/Feature/UploadTest.php:50

FAILURES!
Tests: 5, Assertions: 8, Failures: 1.
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason this isn't going to work is because you're not resolving the Model from the IoC e.g. using `app()` or dependency injection. This will work with facades but not Eloquent models.

You can change the controller method definition to the following to resolve the class from the container:

```
public function upload(Request $request, AnyModel $anyModel)
```

Then your call to `create` would be:

```
$anyModel->create([
    'job_id'  => $fileName
]);
```

---

There are also a couple of issues in your test as well:

1. The fully qualified name for the class is `'App\AnyModel'` not `'\App\AnyModel'`. I would suggest using [::class](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name) instead of using a string i.e. `AnyModel::class` (make sure you've imported the class).
2. You only seem to be calling `create()` once so having `->times(3)` will throw an error.

Comment: I accidentally left `times(3)` when I was trying to get errors from unit testing. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Besides using IoC that @RossWilson talked about, I also found out that I could fall in the catch block by using

```
Storage::shouldReceive('disk')->andThrow('error');
```